# Prove that $f$ is also continuous at $0$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $|f(x)| \leq |g(x)|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $g$ is continuous at zero and $g(0) = 0$. Prove that $f$ is also continuous at $0$.

We are probably going to have to use the definition of the limit here, so we have that $$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta_1 \quad |x| < \delta_1 \quad \implies \quad |g(x)| < \epsilon,$$ and $|f(x)| \leq |g(x)| < \epsilon$. Thus, we have to show $$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta_2 \quad |x| < \delta_2 \quad \implies \quad |f(x) - L| < \epsilon.$$ Then we have $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon \iff L-\epsilon < f(x) < L + \epsilon$. How can we find $\delta_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are so close: You didn't use the tandem of facts that $|f(x)|\leq|g(x)|$ **and** $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$; the latter is implied by continuity of $g$ at zero.

Let positive $\delta_g(\epsilon)$ be small enough that $\forall x:|x|<\delta_g \implies |g(x)-0| < \epsilon$.

Then let $\delta_f(\epsilon) = \delta_g(\epsilon)$.  We have

$$ \forall x:|x|<\delta_f \implies |x|<\delta_g \implies |g(x)-0| < \epsilon \implies |g(x)| < \epsilon \implies  |f(x)| < \epsilon \implies |f(x)-0| < \epsilon
$$
In the next to last step we have made use of the fact that $|f(x)| \leq |g(x)|$.

At any rate, we have shown $\forall x:|x|<\delta_f(\epsilon) \implies |f(x)-0| < \epsilon$ which is the definition of continuity of $f(x)$ at zero.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}|f(x)|\le\lim_{x\to 0}|g(x)|=0.$$

Comment: The limit may not exist so you cannot say that.

Comment: @user19405892: The limit must exist since $g(x) \to 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, that's where I would like to see a $\delta-\epsilon$ proof.

Comment: Whatever $\delta$ works for $g$ must work for $f$.

Comment: @user19405892: I don't understand what you mean. Neither $f,g$ in your comment satisfy the conditions given. You need to show $f$ is continuous at $0$. You know that $f(0) =0$, so if there is a limit, it must be $0$.

Comment: You need to show that for any fixed $\epsilon>0$ that there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $|x| < \delta$ then $|f(x)| < \epsilon$. I don't know what you mean by 'gap'. Since such a $\delta$ exists for $g$, and $|f|\le |g|$, the same $\delta$ **must** work for $f$.

Answer (score 0):

You know that for all $\epsilon>0$ that there is some $\delta>0$ such that
if $|x| < \delta$ then $|g(x)| < \epsilon$.

Hence if $|x| < \delta$, then $|f(x)| \le |g(x)| < \epsilon$, and so
$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$.